# Making animation switching images from imageview (Android)

Tags: android, animation

I'm a newbie with android, and i am making a slot machine game, but can't figure out how get to work the animation of slots. Now i am trying to make the rolling animation with 3 different png files switching over and over, and the logcat says something about frame skips. It just ain't changing images. Sorry for my english.

Method code:

> ```
> public void animation(){
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>       imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot1);
>       imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot2);
>       imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.slot3);
>       android.os.SystemClock.sleep(70);
>   }
> ```

Logcat:

> 05-08 17:06:53.230: I/Choreographer(943): Skipped 74 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling sleep on the main UI thread, you need to run this code from a separate thread or an AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :). Will you please give me a brief explanation on how to run my code on asynctask? I just started learning android and understand anything about asynctask.

Comment: This link might help you get started with this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I kinda get it, but if i run the code on separate class how will i make use of the imageviews from main activity to switch their image?

Comment: So, i already tried making it on a different thread but then logcat says this: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: That is what AsyncTask is designed to do, you can make changes to the UI Views in the onPostExecute method of the class.